# symfony 1.4 form sfWidgetFormInputFile

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I had a problem with sfWidgetFormInputFile symfony 1.4 when I upload my `picto.png` it changes extension of my file to `picto.txt`.
It works fine in my local machine but, in production server, I had this problem.

```
class ImageForm extends BaseImageForm
{
   public function configure()
      {
         $this->widgetSchema['url'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array(
            'label' => 'Image'
            ));

        $this->validatorSchema['url'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
              'required'   => false,
              'mime_types' => array(
                    'image/jpeg',
                    'image/pjpeg',
                    'image/png',
                    'image/x-png',
                    'image/gif'
                ),
              'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/client'
        ));
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: $this->widgetSchema['url'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array(
     'label' => 'Image'
    ));

    $this->validatorSchema['url'] = new sfValidatorFile(array(
     'required'   => false,
        'mime_types' => 'web_images',
        'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/client'
   ));
    $this->validatorSchema['url']->setOption('mime_type_guessers', array(
   array($this->validatorSchema['url'], 'guessFromFileinfo'),
   array($this->validatorSchema['url'], 'guessFromFileBinary'),
   array($this->validatorSchema['url'], 'guessFromMimeContentType')
    ));

Comment: It's rather not a problem with Sf forms. The `sfValidatorFile` hashed the name of the uploaded file and preserves the extension. When you upload a file `picto.png` you should get something like `e3f4f3e9f8a25c5d8a2aa9024eaf18a3.png`